# partition in 18.04 without extended file

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, disk, boot-partition

[This is my disc partion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmoYW.png)

Just install 18.04 I don't how to do partition. I did youtube and google but they did with the help of extend partition in their file. I don't have this. I  don't know why

I want to increase /dev/sda4

And /dev/sda4 is showing 358 GB is unused. I don't know where is this folder.

Please help me out

------ Edit ---

After running some commands I got this out put

[this is the output I get after commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzhlp.png)

`sudo lsblk -f`

`lsblk: failed to access sysfs directory: /sys/dev/block: No such file or directory`

---

`sudo lsblk -m`

`lsblk: failed to access sysfs directory: /sys/dev/block: No such file or directory`

---

`sudo parted -ls`

`Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
    Partition Table: msdos
    Disk Flags:

```
Number  Start   End     Size   Type     File system  Flags
```

`1      1049kB  525MB   524MB  primary  ntfs         boot`
2      525MB   524GB   524GB  primary

`4      524GB   1000GB  476GB  primary  ext4`

```
 `root@mohsin:/# df
```

df: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
root@mohsin:/# sudo df
df: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
root@mohsin:/# df
`

Comment: I would guess/suspect that it is a Windows partition, and that Windows is hibernated or semi-hibernated (alias uses 'fast startup'). This means that Ubuntu should stay away from it to avoid corruption. If you want Ubuntu to see it, you can avoid hibernation and turn off fast startup in Windows, and try again.

Comment: @sudodus What should I do now? should I install again? I want to wipe out windows partition completely please suggest.

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that it is a Windows partition? Or do you want to test it with some command lines (in a terminal window) to be sure? Could there be some data (documents, pictures etc) that you want to copy to another drive or partition before wiping it?

Comment: I am sure this is window partition, of Window 10. But before wipe out  I want to see the data I have. Because after installing Linux I never saw them. Where are those folders?

Comment: Are you able to boot into Windows? If not, please run the following command lines, and edit your original question to add the output. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code' to make it easier to read: `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and `sudo parted -ls` and `df`

Comment: I just added screenshot and output in code also. please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79604/discussion-between-sudodus-and-mohsin).